# how to upgrade 19.04 to 19.10?

Tags: 19.04, 19.10

I have been trying to upgrade version 19.04 to 19.10 but it does not happen.

When I write

```
do-release-upgrade
```

it gives this output

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

When I write

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the following output appears

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsnmp30
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

How to upgrade successfully?

Note: I am adding files which might potentially contain wrong selections in the lists

[image]

[image]

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libsnmp30
```

code gives me this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I wrote this command ( nothing happened)

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

then

sudo apt-get update

gives the result below

```
 Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97,5 
 kB]
 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88,8 
 kB]
 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97,5 
 kB]
 Fetched 284 kB in 3s (107 kB/s)     
 Reading package lists... Done
```

after this used

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove

 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
 libmysqlclient20 mysql-common
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 After this operation, 4.003 kB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 (Reading database ... 185057 files and directories currently 
 installed.)
 Removing libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.19.04.2) ...
 Removing mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
```

then

```
 sudo apt-get update
 Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
 Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
 Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
 Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
 Reading package lists... Done
```

trying to upgrade gives this result with the command

```
 do-release-upgrade
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 Please install all available updates for your release before 
 upgrading.
```

I think I am doing failure at my selections given in the screenshot above.

I tried this,

```
$ sudo apt list | grep python | cut -d "/" -f1 | xargs sudo apt-get 
remove -y
```

errorr occured after a long process I am writing last line (error text)

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I recommend to other users to be careful with applying commands,especially with sudo with which they are not familiar commands. now computer is being opened with only command system and I do not know what to do.

I wrote sudo reboot it reopened but with command line only. writes: 2 updates can be installed immediately 1 of these updates is a security update. I wrote

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and
sudo apt-get upgrade

it writes at last line

```
0 upgraded,o newly installed,o to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103585/discussion-on-question-by-blue89-how-to-upgrade-19-04-to-19-10).

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. **I think** the cause was `libsnmp30` (whatever this is).
So, to solve first kill `libsnmp30` by running:
`sudo apt purge libsnmp30`
`sudo apt autoremove`

Next you upgrade the OS with a command `do-release-upgrade`. If you don't have it, run `sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`.

Then run
`sudo do-release-upgrade -c`

to check the upgrade is what you are desiring.
Finally run
`sudo do-release-upgrade`
and wait for the upgrade to finish (you may get prompts, answer `yes`/`no` accordingly).
Good luck!

Comment: hi,@Tom , it says A new version (tmp/grub.iiJVNCbkJa) of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available,but the version installed currently has been locally modified. What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub? install the package maintenar's version,keep the local version currently installed,Show the differences between available versions, do a 3 way merge between available versions, start a new shell to examine the situation. (which one should be chosen now?) (I shall be thankful for your answer),(appears again at the center of screen)

Comment: (I forgot,there is  one more selection : "show a side by side difference between the versions") which one? (I anticipate and I am about to select "keep the local version currently installed")

Comment: I selected keep the local version currently installed...

Comment: it shows a message on screen: Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.For the first word,TAB lists possible command completions.Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions

Comment: I think ubuntu collapsed...unfortunately.

Comment: @blue89 Collapsed how?

Comment: Everything was appearing very normal until terminal asked, restart is required, do you want to restart now?

Comment: y/N i pressed yes and after that point very strange actions happened i several times made it restart and now nothing happens over the screen, only cursor to write something but when you try to write nothing appears.. Only black screen. All in all it has not been resolved but i should nevertheless thank to you @Tom.